# Emacs how to show only the lines on or before the cursor in a file

Tags: emacs, code-folding

I am a high school computer science teacher and would like to use emacs to present programs to my students.  I would like to be able to present the programs, even short ones, one line at a time and not have the whole program show in the emacs buffer from the start.

Thus I would like emacs to hide all the lines below the current line and reveal each line when I move the cursor down to that line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inspired by your question, I added library [`reveal-next.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/reveal-next.el) to [EmacsWiki](http://www.emacswiki.org).  I think it does what you want.

Comment: Putting the following in my init.el, I was also able to add highlighting of the current line. Thanks. 


(load-file "~/.emacs.d/reveal-next.el")

(defun hide-following-code ()
  (interactive)
  (hl-line-mode t)
  (reveal-next-mode t))
(global-set-key (kbd "C-<down>") 'hide-following-code)

Comment: That just highlights the last line showing, no? BTW, did you notice that if you set `reveal-next-char-level` to t then you can hide/reveal things smaller or bigger than just a line at a time. E.g, you can use `C-M-f` to move forward a sexp, revealing it etc.  Anyway, HTH.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
(defun narrow-next-line ()
  (interactive)
  (widen)
  (call-interactively 'move-end-of-line)
  (forward-char)
  (call-interactively 'move-end-of-line)
  (narrow-to-region 1 (point)))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-x n i") 'narrow-next-line)
```

Choose your own hotkey for this command. See also http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Narrowing.html